# Missing button icons in pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

In my python application I have buttons with icons (png images, see bellow)

[image]

The up and down arrows are buttons.
Now i'm trying to make exe from my python script using pyinstaller, as follow

```
pyinstaller myScript.py
```

But in the generated exe the icon images for buttons are missing

[image]

It seems that pyinstaller should be called with some attributes.

How can I include png icons images of buttons in exe file using pyinstaller?

Comment: have you given the absolute path of png in your script.

Comment: Thanks, it works with absolute paths

Comment: Most likely the absolute path won't work, if you try to move the exe to another pc. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32048136/3837382), if you are building in --onefile mode.