# Icons missing from PyQt5 app after compiling to .exe using pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, pyinstaller

**SOLVED - Solution posted as answer, thanks all for the help.**

After compiling my python application using `PyQt5` to an executable file, the icons contained in my GUI are removed / not displayed.
Specifically `QIcon` instances added to my `Window(QMainWindow)` class using `self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(fpath))` and a `QPixmap(f2path)` embedded in a `QLabel` via `label.setPixmap(myPixmap)`.

I have tried to search on this forum for possible solutions but couldn't find a problem solving thread.
I've tried to set the absolute filepath as recommended here [Bundling data files with PyInstaller (--onefile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile/44352931#44352931) and here [Missing button icons in pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44130289/missing-button-icons-in-pyinstaller)

No idea where to start examining problems, there are no errors when compiling with `pyinstaller` and it runs fine as a python script.

```
pyinstaller -w -F MY_GUI.py
```

Thanks in advance!

---

---

Example:

```
import sys
import os

def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    base_path = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

---

```
import sys
import resource_path # code taken from links above
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title = "MyProg"
        self.top = 400
        self.left = 400
        self.width = 680
        self.height = 540
        icon_path = resource_path("icon.png")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(icon_path))

        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title) 
        self.setGeometry(self.top, self.left, self.width, self.height) 
        self.show()

App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Comment: I've tried 3 times to add a friendly 'Hi there' to the top, wouldn't work..

Comment: provide a [mcve]. How do you add the icons? Do you use a relative or absolute path or do you use qresource?

Comment: @MalteHerrmann Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251077/1288408

Comment: @ModusTollens Thanks, good to know! New around here...

Comment: @MalteHerrmann No problem, glad to help! Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: @MalteHerrmann Are the images on the side of your executable?

Comment: What do you mean? The icon files (png) are in the same folder where the .py file is and the .exe is generated into.

Comment: @MalteHerrmann It seems that `pyinstaller` can't infer that you need this png file (not sure what this `resource_path` does behind the scenes). However there are options to [explicitly include data files](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-data-files) in the resulting bundle. Maybe listing your icons there helps.

Comment: @MalteHerrmann okay, I mean the executable, after you generate the .exe the .py is irrelevant. please use `@username` to notify messages

Comment: @eyllanes the images are all in the same folder as the .exe file is generated, still does not work :(

Comment: @a_guest I'll look into your post when I get back to my laptop, thanks for the link!

Comment: have you tried to compile with `--icon=path_to_icon` option?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determining application path in a Python EXE generated by pyInstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404744/determining-application-path-in-a-python-exe-generated-by-pyinstaller)

Comment: Use that solution, it works for me correctly

Comment: @a_guest THANK YOU! Specifying the images as additional data in the `.spec`-file solved my problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to specifically add the image files to the `.spec` file then generate the `.exe` file using

```
$> pyinstaller myGUI.spec
```

Here is the relevant part of the `.spec` file:

```
a = Analysis(['myGUI.py'],
     ...,
     datas = [('myIcon.png', '.')],
     ...)
```